# How to append nested-object in RealmSwift?

Tags: swift, realm

This is my model and I want to expand "todos" when I add new data:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class TodoData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var date: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var isToday: Bool = true 
    let todos: List<Todo> = List<Todo>()

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "date"
    }

    convenience init(date: String) {
        self.init()
        self.date = date
        self.isToday = isToday
    }
}

class Todo: Object {
    @objc dynamic var dateInt: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var content: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var isDone: Bool = false



    let ofTodo = LinkingObjects(fromType: TodoData.self, property: "todos")

    convenience init(dateInt: Int,title: String, content: String, isDone: Bool) {
        self.init()
        self.dateInt = dateInt
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.isDone = isDone
    }
}
```

ex. when adding new data from textfield ipnut text, the main todos data is overwritten.
so how can I implement append new Todo , not being updated?

```
try! self.realm.write {
    let main = TodoData(date: now)
    let sub = Todo(dateInt: todayInt, title: title, content: content, isDone: isDone)
            
                            
    main.todos.append(sub)
    self.realm.add(main, update: Realm.UpdatePolicy.all)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going through too many steps with saving the Realm so let's simplify!

Lets set this up with a PersonClass that has dogs

```
class PersonClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var name = ""
   list dogList = List<DogClass>()
}
```

and then a DogClass which uses linkingObject for a path back to it's owner(s)

```
class DogClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var name = ""
   let linkingPerson = LinkingObjects(fromType: PersonClass.self, property: "dogList")
```

and then instantiate  a person and a dog and add the dog the persons List

```
let person = PersonClass()
person.name = "Jay"

let dog = DogClass()
dog.name = "Rover"

person.dogList.append(dog)

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(person) //this add the person *and* the dog to Realm
}
```

Then to address your question, suppose later on our person gets a new dog

let's load the person

```
let realm = try Realm()
let person = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter("name == 'Jay'").first!
```

then create the dog

```
let anotherDog = DogClass()
anotherDog.name = "Spot"
```

then, and this is the important bit, add the dog to the *person* within the write, which will add the dog to Realm as well as adding it to the persons list - all in one statement.

```
try! realm.write {
   person.dogList.append(anotherDog)
}
```

Note you should not do this `.first!` but I did it for brevity in this answer. You should always safely handle and unwrap optionals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! my problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

self answer

```
try! self.realm.write {
            
    let sub = Todo(title: title, content: content, isDone: isDone)
            
    if let old = self.realm.objects(TodoData.self).filter("dateInt == \(todayInt)").first {
        old.todos.append(sub)
    } else {
        let main = TodoData(date: now, dateInt: todayInt)
        main.todos.append(sub)
        self.realm.add(main, update: Realm.UpdatePolicy.all)
    }
}
```